# Why QApplication::notify throw exception?

Tags: qt

I try to catch exception thrown by QApplication::notify as follows:

```
  bool done = true;
  try {
    done = QApplication::notify(receiver, event);
  } catch (const std::exception &ex) {
    qDebug()<< "receiver:" << receiver->objectName();
    qDebug()<< "event type:" << event->type();
    qDebug()<< "exception:" << ex.what();
  }
```

exception log is like:

receiver: "curImageTestRunPushButton"
event type: QEvent::MouseButtonRelease
exception: device or resource busy: device or resource busy

I am wondering why this exception is thrown and in what situation QApplication::notify throws exception?

I just want to known why this exception is thrown and in what situation QApplication::notify throws exception?

Comment: What makes you think it's `QApplication::notify` that throws?  It's far more likely the exception comes from the user code processing the event.  Use a debugger to locate the source of the `throw` statement.

Comment: but i did not process the MouseButtonRelease  event of curImageTestRunPushButton, i just process the ButtonPress event by on_curImageTestRunPushButton_clicked() function

Comment: @WangHui That's irrelevant. `clicked` is emitted as result of the implementation of QAbstractButton's `mouseReleaseEvent()` and happens *within* that handler, meaning that it doesn't matter where the function connected to that signal is implemented: the receiver is the widget that *receives the event*, which eventually **may** trigger a signal that calls the connected slots. Events are sent to objects handling them, not to objects connected to their signals, and for an obvious reasons: that's not the purpose of signals. They don't handle events, they are *one* of their possible consequences.

Comment: @WangHui Signals are not events: you're not processing the "button press event", you're just "processing" the signal that results from that event. If you connected the `clicked` signal of `A` to `B::function()`, the "receiver" will still be `A`, which makes sense, since: 1. as said, the receiver is the object to which an event will be sent; 2. `B` doesn't need to be a QObject (and Qt can only send QEvents to QObjects); 3. you can even connect to lambdas, which obviously are not QObjects. Check again what `on_curImageTestRunPushButton_clicked` does, because the culprit is most certainly there.